# LINQ (LAMBDA) Como itero outra lista de objetos e adiciono no meu where? c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Boa tarde, estou fazendo uma aplicação em C# .Net Core, usando lambda para manuseio do contexto de banco de dados.
Estou com uma dúvida, que é a seguinte:
Tenho uma lista de objetos com esses dois atributos:
Name e StartDate.
Algo como:

```
List<Operations> operations = new List<Operations>();
operations.Add(new Operation() { Name: "Exemplo 1", StartDate: "2018-07-02 00:00:00" };
operations.Add(new Operation() { Name: "Exemplo 2", StartDate: "2017-05-01 13:00:00" };
```

Agora gostaria de fazer um lambda no meu contexto, iterando essa lista com uma condição com o operador "OR". 
Algo que ficaria assim no SQL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    contact t
WHERE
    (t.OperationName = "Exemplo 1" AND t.ContactDate > "2018-07-02 00:00:00")
    OR (t.OperationName = "Exemplo 1" AND t.ContactDate > "2017-05-01 13:00:00")
```

Mas não estou conseguindo.
As condições de dentro do parenteses serem separadas por AND, quando dizerem respeito ao mesmo objeto, e separando os objetos por OR.
Estou usando Lambda, algo como segue abaixo:

```
dbContext.Teste.Where(x => x...);
```

@EDIT:
Um Fiddle que eu fiz para demonstração do meu problema:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/DqvOx4

Nesse Fiddle, consigo apenas fazer o where com o primeiro obj de operations, mas preciso iterar por todos objetos.
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso usando Lambda?

Comment: Você já escreveu a resposta com a solução. Não escrevemos respostas nas perguntas, nem tampouco pomos "resolvido" no título

Comment: Certo, e como eu marco que a pergunta foi resolvida?

Comment: Você já o fez quando marcou a sua própria resposta com o vezinho verde. Veja mais [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/64969)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema.

A maneira que uma lista pode ser iterada sobre outra, é usando a função "Any()" da segunda lista, dentro da condição da primeira.
Segue fiddle com o problema resolvido:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/QuXwQZ

TL;DR: Trecho do código que resolveu o problema:

```
List<Contact> listaResultado = 
contacts
.Where(
    x => 
        operations.Any(
            y => 
                x.OperationName.Equals(y.Name) 
                && x.ContactDate > y.StartDate
        )
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar `AND` e `OR` com lambda usa-se o operador `&&` e `||`

Vamos supor que você tenha seguinte classe:

```
public class Operation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Com isso podemos criar(Simulando dados do banco) uma lista de operações da seguinte forma

```
List<Operation> operations = new List<Operation>
{
    new Operation() { Name= "Exemplo 1", StartDate= Convert.ToDateTime("2018-07-02 00:00:00") },
    new Operation() { Name = "Exemplo 2", StartDate= Convert.ToDateTime("2017-05-01 13:00:00") },
    new Operation() { Name = "Exemplo 3", StartDate= Convert.ToDateTime("2016-05-01 13:00:00") }
};
```

Agora iremos fazer uma pesquisa nessa lista e jogar os dados selecionados em outra lista da seguinte forma

```
List<Operation> operationsDois = operations.Where(x => (x.Name == "Exemplo 1" && x.StartDate == Convert.ToDateTime("2018-07-02 00:00:00")) || (x.Name == "Exemplo 2" && x.StartDate == Convert.ToDateTime("2017-05-01 13:00:00"))).ToList();
```

Aqui um exemplo pesquisando por data, irá pegar dos últimos 30 dias

```
List<Operation> operationsTres = operations.Where(x => x.StartDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) && x.StartDate <= DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

Com isso a segunda lista tem as informações pesquisadas.

---

Quando é feito um `Where` ele irá passar por todos dados verificando com quais irá "casar", para jogar isso numa lista você pode fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
List<Teste> testes = dbContext.Teste.Where(x => (x.Name == "" && x.StartDate == "") || (x.Name == "" && x.StartDate == "")).ToList();
```

Comment: Certo, mas como faço para todos os objetos da lista? Nesse seu exemplo ficaria apenas 2 objetos. Como aplico algo como um for-each na lista?

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se ficou mais claro, o `where` irá passar em todos dados da lista, tendo 2 ou mais

Comment: Acho que ainda não está da maneira q eu preciso... Para você entender, tanto a classe Operation quanto o objeto Teste do banco tem os mesmos parâmetros. Então quero pesquisar todos os objetos de Teste que casam com o filtro dos objetos de Operations, entendeu? Da forma que você fez n é exatamente isso.

Comment: Não entendi.. você tem dois objetos com os mesmos campos e quer pesquisar tanto 1 quanto o outro com os mesmos "termos" de pesquisa? a ultima linha de código que adicionei é a mesma da `query sql` que você adicionou na pergunta

Comment: Para contextualizar você: Eu tenho uma lista de operações cadastradas, que servirão de parâmetro para minha busca na classe Teste. A classe teste tem vários outros atributos, além dos que a classe operação também tem, eu quero realizar um filtro na classe Teste sobre todos os objetos que contém as informações da lista de operações que eu peguei. O único problema da sua linha de código, a não ser q eu esteja errado, ele está iterando apenas 2 objetos na condição, mas esta lista de operações pode, e vai ter muito mais que dois objetos.

Comment: De uma olhada nesse [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wdS9j4), eu criei uma lista com 6 itens e estou fazendo um where para me retornar apenas 2 dados. a tabela no banco pode ter milhares de dados, quando é feito o where do lambda irá retornar apenas as informações que "casarem" com o que foi pesquisado.

Comment: Ela não irá iterando apenas 2 objetos, mas sim dois campos do objeto, se eu fizer `p=> p.Name = "Exemplo"` irá retornar todos itens que tem o `Name` **Exemplo**, seja 1 ou 100 itens. Acho que estou entendendo o que quer.. você seja fazer algo como join? exemplo onde **Teste.Name = Operation.Name?**

Comment: Olha, me desculpe mas acho que eu me esclareci de maneira errada. Fiz um Fiddle para você ter uma ideia do que quero fazer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DqvOx4 Na "listaResultado" eu quero buscar todos os contatos, mas usando os objetos de operação como filtro. Nesse caso eu só busquei o primeiro da lista de Operaçoes, usando o FirstOrDefault. Eu quero iterar sobre todos objetos dessa lista. Deu para compreender?

Comment: Confirma se é isso, por favor https://dotnetfiddle.net/grAVrg. Eu apenas removi o ultimo filtro porque não tinha nenhum match, mas deixei comentado em baixo.

Comment: É quase isso, mas como você fez dois selects, desse jeito, o primeiro p (do primeiro select) e o segundo p (do segundo select) seria referente ao msm objeto? Além disso, a data tem q ser uma condição de ">" (maior que). Como fazer isso usando o select, se o x é uma lista?

Comment: Na verdade não são dois selects, na lista que uso o P estou pegando(selecionando) apenas os nomes, é o equivalente ao `IN` do `SQL`, quanto ao >, me tira uma duvida, você precisa que quando ter "match" do nome, a data seja maior que a do objeto que deu "match"?  Atualizei aqui para ficar melhor visível a questão do select https://dotnetfiddle.net/grAVrg

Comment: Entendi. Sim, o match tem q ser do nome e a data do objeto que deu match.

Comment: Entendi o que você deseja, seria valido você editar a pergunta e adicionar essas informações, incluindo o Fiddle, só vou conseguir parar para ver mais a noite, ai pode ser que outra pessoa possa te ajudar(por ora vou manter a resposta caso alguém entre veja o histórico, mas a noite removo ela pq não responde a pergunta.)

Comment: @RenanGonzales veja se é isso que deseja (https://dotnetfiddle.net/grAVrg)

Comment: É quase isso. Só que dessa maneira, para cada operação vai ser feito uma query diferente no banco (eu tentei implementar do jeito q vc falou e adicionei um trace no banco para ter certeza disso). E, um outro problema é q eu tenho que pegar os top 1000 ordenados por ID, por exemplo, e se fizer query separada ele n vai pegar na ordem correta.

Comment: Compreendo, meu conhecimento de LINQ impede que eu consiga pensar em outra forma de resolver isso com Lambda, talvez com SQL eu consiga, te ajudaria em algo? se sim, o banco é sql-sever?

Comment: Eu tbm não tenho tanto conhecimento assim. Mas não tem problema nenhum, em SQL eu consegui fazer já. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Se puder deixar a resposta ai, agradeço. Pois tem muita conversa e explicação nela.

Comment: Blz, mantenho sim.